# Persistent question mark icon in Wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel, icons

first post ...

A few days ago, a Question Mark icon appeared in my Wingpanel..

[image: a Question Mark icon appeared in my Wingpanel.]

Why is it there, and how can I make it go away?!

If I click it, I get a tiny dialogue box with no dialogue in it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix this strange icon in wingpanel?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/how-can-i-fix-this-strange-icon-in-wingpanel)

Comment: I am going to guess that this is not actually a duplicate, it is significantly different.