# How can I fix this strange icon in wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel, icons

[image]

The top left icon.

No idea what can it be. I havent installed anything new, just when i started my computer it was there. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be the dropbox indicator. It was also broken for me.

Comment: @Benni You are right, its the dropbox indicator. How can i fix it without reinstalling dropbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How to find out which application indicator is broken

You can end the process of each application you are used to see wing-panel step by step and see when the broken indicator hides.

In my case it was the Dropbox indicator.

#### How to fix the Dropbox indicator

You can run the following script from Nathan Dyer to fix it:
https://github.com/nathandyer/elementary-dropbox-mods

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can know which applications are using indicators (other than the *elementaryOS* defaults) executing on terminal:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=com.canonical.indicator.application /com/canonical/indicator/application/service com.canonical.indicator.application.service.GetApplications | grep "object path"
```

See the output to find what applications are running with an indicator.

Answer (score 2):

since the link in accepted answer is already invalid, I'd like to give another link. The link below contains custom install script for DropBox.

https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox

This requires re-install of Dropbox, however.

Answer (score 0):

The likely culprit is Dropbox as others have mentioned, since Dropbox does not recognize elementary OS's Desktop interface.

This solution will not require a reinstall of Dropbox. I would however recommend running `dropbox stop` from the terminal. Once you have completed the below steps, you can restart the service by running `dropbox start`.

The easiest and most straight forward solution is to add the following lines to `/usr/bin/dropbox`, just after `import os`

```
os.environ['XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP']="Unity"
os.environ['QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE']="''"
```

[image: /usr/bin/dropbox Example]